# Got this error 'Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone)'

Tags: java

Whenever I run maven clean or maven build or maven in install got error like one of its dependencies could not be resolved Could not transfer artifact. any solution I found on internet is not working. how to solve it to export war file.

I want to resolve it and export war or jar file.